# How to identify similar tables in two databases and analyze column differences

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have two databases with several tables. Now I need to find the column differences in the same table in both databases.

**For example:** in DB1 I have a table named TEMP and its columns are PersonID, LastNamee, FirstName, Address, City, and DB2 I have a table with the same name TEMP and its columns are ID, FirstName, LastName, Address, City.

**I created this query.**

```
SELECT 
A.TABLE_CATALOG,
A.TABLE_NAME,
A.COLUMN_NAME,
B.TABLE_CATALOG,
B.TABLE_NAME,
B.COLUMN_NAME,
'COLUMN Not Match' AS RESULT
FROM DB1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS A FULL OUTER JOIN DB2.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS B 
ON A.TABLE_NAME = B.TABLE_NAME AND B.COLUMN_NAME = A.COLUMN_NAME
INNER JOIN DB2.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS BB 
ON A.TABLE_NAME = BB.TABLE_NAME
WHERE B.TABLE_NAME IS NULL OR B.TABLE_NAME IS NULL AND A.TABLE_NAME= BB.TABLE_NAME
```

**I'm got the following results for this query:**

```
TABLE_CATALOG   | TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | TABLE_CATALOG | TABLE_NAME  | COLUMN_NAME 
DB1                 temp         PersonID        NULL           NULL          NULL
DB1                 temp         PersonID        NULL           NULL          NULL
DB1                 temp         PersonID        NULL           NULL          NULL
DB1                 temp         PersonID        NULL           NULL          NULL
DB1                 temp         PersonID        NULL           NULL          NULL
DB1                 temp         LastNamee       NULL           NULL          NULL
DB1                 temp         LastNamee       NULL           NULL          NULL
DB1                 temp         LastNamee       NULL           NULL          NULL
DB1                 temp         LastNamee       NULL           NULL          NULL
DB1                 temp         LastNamee       NULL           NULL          NULL
```

**What results should I expect?**

```
TABLE_CATALOG   | TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | TABLE_CATALOG | TABLE_NAME  | COLUMN_NAME 
DB1                 temp         PersonID        DB2            temp          ID
DB1                 temp         LastNamee       DB2            temp          LastName
```

My condition is if the table matches in both databases, I verify the two tables columns, if the columns do not match, I return the not matching columns.

I'm not sure how to achieve it. kindly assist me.

Comment: In your desired output you tell that DB1.temp.PersonID is related to DB2.temp.ID. What data allowed you to make such a conclusion? datatype? datalength? nullability? the presence in primary key expression? some combination of the above facts? something esle?

Comment: pardon I'm not sure what you're asking. However, I'm not sure which data will assist me in identifying the expected output. @Akina

Comment: Note that AND goes before OR.

Comment: *I'm not sure which data will assist me in identifying the expected output.* This means that you do not understand your task completely now. But nobody can do this except you. So you must think. Investigate the data received for both tables/columns and decide which parameters allows to make a conclusion that some columns pair matches each other.

Comment: Those datas are just Table catalog, Table schema, Table name, Column name, Is nullable, Data type, and Char max len. I believe the only way to determine the difference is to use Table catalog, Table schema, Table name, and Column name.@Akina

Comment: @jarlh Not working

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: MySQL Server @jarlh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a sub-query to select only the table that you are interested before doing a full outer join

```
select  db1.TABLE_CATALOG, db1.TABLE_NAME, db1.COLUMN_NAME,
        db2.TABLE_CATALOG, db2.TABLE_NAME, db2.COLUMN_NAME
from    (
            select  TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
            from    DB1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS t1
            where   exists
                    (
                         select *
                         from   DB2.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t2
                         where  t2.TABLE_NAME = t1.TABLE_NAME 
                    )
        ) db1
        full outer join 
        (
            select  TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
            from    DB2.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS t2
            where   exists
                    (
                         select *
                         from   DB2.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t1
                         where  t1.TABLE_NAME = t2.TABLE_NAME 
                    )
        ) db2   on  db1.TABLE_NAME  = db2.TABLE_NAME
                and db1.COLUMN_NAME = db2.COLUMN_NAME
where   (
            db1.COLUMN_NAME is null
        or  db2.COLUMN_NAME is null
        )
```

Comment: I'd want to verify all the tables in both databases like you did, however you just checked just that one

Comment: just remove the `WHERE` clause if you want to compare all tables. I added the where clause because you mention a table `TEMP` in the question

Comment: If I remove the ```WHERE``` clause, all tables and columns are shown; I just want the unmatched columns tables only.

Comment: then add to outer query `WHERE db1.COLUMN_NAME is null or db2.COLUMN_NAME is null`

Comment: Yes, it displays the tables with unmatched columns, as well as the names of tables that are missing.

Comment: edited. Is this what you want ?

Comment: Actually, if both databases have the same table, I'd want to compare the table's columns to see how they differ. That is a different scenario if the table is missing.

Comment: isn't the last edited query doing this ?

Comment: Sincerely apologies. I state at the top of my question what outcome I expect. "If the table exists in both databases, test the two tables columns; if the columns do not match, I return the columns that do not match."

Comment: think i understand you now .. . edited

Comment: I've already written a query that displays tables with mismatched columns and the names of tables that are missing. I'm not sure how to separate only columns that aren't matched.

Comment: I've been looking for a solution to the column mismatch problem for more than two days and have yet to discover one. my old query ```SELECT ISNULL(A.TABLE_CATALOG,B.TABLE_CATALOG) LOG ,ISNULL(A.TABLE_NAME, B.TABLE_NAME) TAB,ISNULL(A.COLUMN_NAME,B.COLUMN_NAME) COL, 'COLUMN is mismatch ' AS RES
FROM db1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS A FULL OUTER JOIN db2.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS B 
ON  A.TABLE_NAME = B.TABLE_NAME AND A.COLUMN_NAME = B.COLUMN_NAME WHERE A.COLUMN_NAME IS NULL OR B.COLUMN_NAME IS NULL ```

Comment: And, does my query works for you ?

Comment: Yes, your query is really quite beneficial to me. Now that I've fixed the problem, I've written a new query that meets my requirements.